# Is there an intuitive explanation for the maximal ergodic theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

The maximal ergodic theorem states that for an $L^1$ integrable function the set $$E(f)=\{x : \max_n\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(T^i(x))\right)>0\}$$ has the property that $\int_{E(f)} f d \mu \geq 0$.  The only time I've seen it used is to prove Birkhoff's ergodic theorem by showing that the set of points where the $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ of the average of the interations of $T$ is not equal has measure zero.  Does the maximal ergodic theorem say anything interesting or is it just a clever tool?

Comment: I think the Theorem is primarily in view of/motivation for Birkhoff's Ergodic Theorem, but it's an interesting statement in its own right. It loosely says that if the time average of a function is positive than the spatial average must also be positive and conversely when the time average is negative the spatial average is also negative.  

This kind or "morally" motivates the Birkhoff's Ergodic Theorem via the following question: If one function's positivity or negativity determines the positivity or negativity of another function, are these two functions equal?

Comment: Interesting explanation.  Thanks